# How to Dockerize a Django + Postgres App with Apache (Instead of NGINX) for production

Tags: django, apache, docker, nginx

I'm new to the DevOps world and I have been following [this tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/#nginx) successfully, my Docker setup is almost identical to the one on the tutorial. I now would like to setup a Docker container with Django and Postgres but with Apache instead of NGINX for production. What commands should I add/modify to the Dockerfile, volumes and configurations to the docker-compose file and what configuration files should I have for the Apache configuration?